# When I used chan to pass the argument, I didn't get the expected result

Tags: go, parameters, channel

code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Dto struct {
    Name string
    Age  int64
}

func Deal(in <-chan *Dto, out chan<- *Dto) {
    in1 := <-in
    newDto := &Dto{
        Name: in1.Name,
        Age:  in1.Age,
    }
    if in1.Name == "xiao1" {
        newDto.Age += 100
    }
    out <- in1
}

func main() {
    in, out := make(chan *Dto), make(chan *Dto)
    contents := []*Dto{
        &Dto{Name: "xiao", Age: 18},
        &Dto{Name: "xiao1", Age: 19},
        &Dto{Name: "xiao2", Age: 20},
        &Dto{Name: "xiao3", Age: 21},
        &Dto{Name: "xiao4", Age: 22},
    }
    for _, v := range contents {
        go func() {
            in <- v
        }()
        go Deal(in, out)
    }
    count := len(contents)
    for index := 0; index < count; index++ {
        fmt.Println(<-out)
    }
    close(in)
    fmt.Println("end")
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Minute)
}
```

actual output

```
    &{xiao4 22}
    &{xiao4 22}
    &{xiao4 22}
    &{xiao4 22}
    &{xiao4 22}
```

expected output

```
    &{xiao 18}
    &{xiao1 119}
    &{xiao2 20}
    &{xiao3 21}
    &{xiao4 22}
```

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables

Comment: See the FAQ: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: so good,Your answer is exactly what I want.  for _, v := range contents {
  go func(v1 *Dto) {
   in <- v1
  }(v)
  go Deal(in, out)
 }